# Using putIfAbsent like a short circuit operator

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

Is it possible to use putIfAbsent or any of its equivalents like a short circuit operator.

```
myConcurrentMap.putIfAbsent(key,calculatedValue)
```

I want that if there is already a calculatedValue it shouldnt be calculated again. 
by default putIfAbsent would still do the calculation every time even though it will not actually store the value again.

Comment: This is where a closure could be an elegant solution. ;)

Comment: You could have a `putIfAbsent(Key, Callable<Value>)` method and call it with `putIfAbsent(Key, {=> return calculation();})`

Comment: @Peter, however `putIfAbsent` API like you suggest brings some interesting implementation issues wrt to calling same closure multiple times on different threads, locking, blocking and atomicity.

Comment: @Peter, It would depend on the implementation, however for ConcurrentHashMap it does use locks internally, however it could result in a putIfAbsent blocking which may undesirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider to use a [Guava ComputingMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/index.html)

```
ConcurrentMap<Key, Value> myConcurrentMap = new MapMaker()
  .makeComputingMap(
    new Function<Key, Value>() {
      public Value apply(Key key) {
        Value calculatedValue = calculateValue(key);
        return calculatedValue;
      }
  });
```

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but it kind of violates the atomic non-blocking properties of `putIfAbsent` - in particular, calls to `get` may "block" while the object is created.  As I noted in my answer, if small amounts of blocking are acceptable then the best solution is likely to just be `synchronize`-ing.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't allow any form of short-circuiting save the built-in cases, sadly - all method calls result in the arguments being fully evaluated before control passes to the method.  Thus you couldn't do this with "normal" syntax; you'd need to manually wrap up the calculation inside a `Callable` or similar, and then explicitly invoke it.

---

In this case I find it difficult to see how it could work anyway, though.  `putIfAbsent` works on the basis of being an atomic, non-blocking operation.  If it were to do what you want, the sequence of events would roughly be:

1. Check if `key` exists in the map (this example assumes it doesn't)
2. Evaluate `calculatedValue` (probably expensive, given the context of the question)
3. Put result in map

It would be impossible for this to be non-blocking if the value didn't already exist at step two - two different threads calling this method at the same time could only perform correctly if blocking happened.  At this point you may as well just use `synchronized` blocks with the flexibility of implementation that that entails; you can definitely implement what you're after with some simple locking, something like the following:

```
private final Map<K, V> map = ...;

public void myAdd(K key, Callable<V> valueComputation) {
    synchronized(map) {
        if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
            map.put(key, valueComputation.call());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ConcurrentMap isn't necessarily non-blocking. It is implemented using locks internally, although on smaller segments, not on entire map. With many writer threads, blocking is still possible though. According to documentation, "Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block", but there is no guarantee on writing operations.

Comment: Good point, I was thinking of the `Atomic*` classes' `compareAndSet` behaviour and expanding it to the entire map.  Still, the first paragraph summarises the main question, I feel.

Comment: Yes I think its easiest to synchronize. Trying to do this with putIfAbsent is overkill. Also like your explanation of why this is against the basic principal.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `Future<V>` objects into the map. Using `putIfAbsent`, only one object will be there, and computation of final value will be performed by calling `Future.get()` (e.g. by `FutureTask`  + `Callable` classes). Check out [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/) for discussion about using this technique. (Example code is also in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886485/in-java-concurrency-in-practice-by-brian-goetz) here on SO.

This way, your value is computed only once, and all threads get same value. Access to map isn't blocked, although access to value (through `Future.get()`) will block until this value is computed by one of the threads.